# How to “splat” the function arguments for dynamically created function

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I am generating some functions in the module:

```
defmodule M do
  funs = [do_it: [:arg1, :arg2]]

  Enum.each(funs, fn {name, args} ->
    args = Enum.map(args, & {&1, [], Elixir})
    def unquote(name)(unquote(args)),
      do: IO.inspect(unquote(args))
  end)
end
```

The issue is the generated function obviously accepts one single argument, namely a list of size 2:

```
▶ M.__info__(:functions) 
#⇒ [do_it: 1]
```

The goal is to dynamically declare the function accepting *two* arguments. In ruby terminology, it would be *to unsplat* argument list.

Is there a possibility to accomplish this without pattern matching the resulting AST for `{:do_it, blah, [[ list of arguments ]]}` and flattening the list manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote_splicing/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote_splicing/1) to "splice" in the `args` list:

```
defmodule M do
  funs = [do_it: [:arg1, :arg2], do_it: [:arg1, :arg2, :arg3]]

  Enum.each(funs, fn {name, args} ->
    def unquote(name)(unquote_splicing(args)), do: :ok
  end)
end
```

```
iex(1)> M.__info__(:functions)
[do_it: 2, do_it: 3]
```